# How to properly use savefiledialog for executables?

Tags: vb.net

I have been wanting to know if it's possible to use savefiledialog for executables in VB.NET. Ive tried doing it with a form, but it seems to bring up "This app can't run on your PC". Here is the coding of what I attempted to use:

```
Public Class MainForm

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog
        sfd.Filter = "Executable |*.exe"
        sfd.ShowDialog()

        Dim writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(sfd.FileName)
        writer.Write(Form2)
        writer.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do?  Writing a form to a stream file named `.exe` wont create an executable

Comment: I'm afraid you are taking the wrong approach here. `StreamWriter` won't convert your _form_ to an _executable_. But if you are trying to make a copy of your exe to some location/filepath which can be taken from a `SaveFileDialog` you can use **File.Copy**

Comment: In order to create a standalone program of your form you need to have access to its source code from inside your app. Then you need to _compile_ that code into an executable file. This process is a lot harder than what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Thanks guys! I knew I was doing something wrong! I appreciate your help and support! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, you should be checking the **return value** of `ShowDialog()` to see if the user clicked "OK" (instead of just cancelling the dialog), otherwise you'll be attempting to use a filename that the user didn't even select:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog
    sfd.Filter = "Executable |*.exe"
    If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        ' ... do something with "sfd.FileName" ...
        Console.WriteLine(sfd.FileName)
    End If
End Sub
```

The SaveFileDialog() simply gives you a way for the user to visually select a FileName.  What you do with that filename is a completely different issue...